# EDI equivalent in the .net world

Tags: c#, .net, biztalk, edi

I work for a small company. Currently we are re-writing our legacy application in C#. There is one part of the application that uses EDI, and I don't know where to look for solutions in the .net world. I have heard about BizTalk but not sure as to if that is the solution. Also there is no BizTalk Express edition like SQL Server Express Edition. In one of the dotnet podcasts I heard a compelling case for Microsoft to put out a Developer Edition for BizTalk.

Can someone shed some more light on this issue?

Comment: For X12, EdiFact & Tradacoms there is [Edi.Net](https://github.com/indice-co/EDI.Net). Its opensource, supports custom POCO clr deserialization and its quite modern (for EDI standards that is). _Disclaimer_ I wrote the lib

Answer (score 3):

As Tim says, EDI is just a "standard" way of interpreting flat files. The various messaging formats are:

1. **X12**
2. **EDIFACT (ORDERS, INVOIC, DESADV...)**
3. **TRADACOM (ORDHDR, ACKHDR,
   **INVFIL...)**

So you will need to read in the data and "map" the required fields. The best way to do this is with FileHelper:

http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/

you would need map the data to your specific BackOffice business rules. What we do here for **Inbound**

1. Receive the file in its raw EDI state
2. Unwrap it, as all EDI data should be wrapped (Due to VAN cost on MB-per-second)
3. Double check we have all the required mandatory fields (PRE-PROCESSOR)
4. Convert the raw EDI file to our Back Office proprierty file system ready to be processed.

Obiviously packages like BizTalk and SAP EDocs will do the PRE-PROCESSOR/Conversion routines for you, but if you want to develop this yourself, i would use FileHelpers mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

EDI is simply a "standard" way to format text files with various business information like orders, invoices, bills of lading etc.

It is unlikely that there would be any specific .NET component for them, because although there is a "standard" defined for EDI it is interpreted slightly differently by every company that uses it.

The standard comprises "business rules", like "you should respond with an 810 document file when you recieve an 850 document file ... as well as the basic file formats of those documents.

[The Wikipedia article explains it pretty thoroughly ...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Data_Interchange)

Answer (score 0):

[RDPCrystal EDI Library](http://rdpcrystal.com/products.html)

[Sparrow technologies EDI Parser](http://www.sparrow-technologies.com/ediparser.net.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [RDPCrystal EDI Library](http://rdpcrystal.com/products.html) is probably what you are looking for.